# Replacing XElement content with XElement

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xelement

Is there a way to selectively replace XElement content with other XElements?

I have this XML:

```
<prompt>
   There is something I want to tell you.[pause=3]
   You are my favorite caller today.[pause=1]
   Have a great day!
</prompt>
```

And I want to render it as this:

```
<prompt>
   There is something I want to tell you.<break time="3s"/>
   You are my favorite caller today.<break time="1s"/>
   Have a great day!
</prompt>
```

I need to replace the placeholders with actual XElements, but when I try to alter the content of an XElement, .NET of course escapes all of the angle brackets.  I understand why the content would normally need to be correctly escaped, but I need to bypass that behavior and inject XML directly into content.

Here's my code that would otherwise work.

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(content, @"\[(\w+)=(\d+)]");
foreach (XElement element in voiceXmlDocument.Descendants("prompt"))
{
    if (matches[0] == null)
        continue;
    element.Value = element.Value.Replace(matches[0].Value, @"<break time=""5s""/>");
}
```

This is a work in progress, so don't worry so much about the validity of the RegEx pattern, as I will work that out later to match several conditions.  This is proof of concept code and the focus is on replacing the placeholders as described.  I only included the iteration and RegEx code here to illustrate that I need to be able to do this to a whole document that is already populated with content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `XElement.Parse()` method:

First, get the outer xml of your XElement, for example,

```
string outerXml = element.ToString();
```

The you have exactly this string to work with:

```
<prompt>
  There is something I want to tell you.[pause=3]
  You are my favorite caller today.[pause=1]
  Have a great day!
</prompt>
```

Then you can do your replacement

```
outerXml = outerXml.Replace(matches[0].Value, @"<break time=""5s""/>");
```

Then you can parse it back:

```
XElement repElement = XElement.Parse(outerXml);
```

And, finally, replace original XElement:

```
element.ReplaceWith(repElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

The key to all of this is the `XText`, which allows you to work with text as an element.

This is the loop:

```
foreach (XElement prompt in voiceXmlDocument.Descendants("prompt"))
{
    string text = prompt.Value;  
    prompt.RemoveAll();
    foreach (string phrase in text.Split('['))
    {
        string[] parts = phrase.Split(']');
        if (parts.Length > 1)
        {
            string[] pause = parts[0].Split('=');
            prompt.Add(new XElement("break", new XAttribute("time", pause[1])));
            // add a + "s" if you REALLY want it, but then you have to get rid
            // of it later in some other code.
        }
        prompt.Add(new XText(parts[parts.Length - 1]));
    }
}
```

This is the end result

```
<prompt>
      There is something I want to tell you.<break time="3" />
      You are my favorite caller today.<break time="1" />
      Have a great day!
</prompt>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xml = 
            @"<prompt>There is something I want to tell you.[pause=3] You are my favorite caller today.[pause=1] Have a great day!</prompt>";

        var voiceXmlDocument = XElement.Parse(xml);

        var pattern = new Regex(@"\[(\w+)=(\d+)]");

        foreach (var element in voiceXmlDocument.DescendantsAndSelf("prompt"))
        {
            var matches = pattern.Matches(element.Value);

            foreach (var match in matches)
            {
                var matchValue = match.ToString();

                var number = Regex.Match(matchValue, @"\d+").Value;

                var newValue = string.Format(@"<break time=""{0}""/>", number);

                element.Value = element.Value.Replace(matchValue, newValue); 
            }

        }

        Console.WriteLine(voiceXmlDocument.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, my goodness, you guys were quicker than I expected!  So, thanks for that, however in the meantime, I solved it a slightly different way.  The code here looks expanded from before because once I got it working, I added some specifics into this particular condition:

```
foreach (XElement element in voiceXmlDocument.Descendants("prompt").ToArray())
{
    // convert the element to a string and see to see if there are any instances
    // of pause placeholders in it
    string elementAsString = element.ToString();
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(elementAsString, @"\[pause=(\d+)]");
    if (matches == null || matches.Count == 0)
        continue;
    // if there were no matches or an empty set, move on to the next one

    // iterate through the indexed matches
    for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
    {
        int pauseValue = 0; // capture the original pause value specified by the user
        int pauseMilliSeconds = 1000; // if things go wrong, use a 1 second default
        if (matches[i].Groups.Count == 2) // the value is expected to be in the second group
        {
            // if the value could be parsed to an integer, convert it from 1/8 seconds to milliseconds
            if (int.TryParse(matches[i].Groups[1].Value, out pauseValue))
                pauseMilliSeconds = pauseValue * 125; 
        }

        // replace the specific match with the new <break> tag content
        elementAsString = elementAsString.Replace(matches[i].Value, string.Format(@"<break time=""{0}ms""/>", pauseMilliSeconds));
    }

    // finally replace the element by parsing
    element.ReplaceWith(XElement.Parse(elementAsString));
}
```

Comment: Funny. I had the same idea.

Comment: Yeah, you did, Alex, and had I not been so stubborn, I would have moved on to something else and checked back for an answer.  In the interest of good karma, I'm going to mark your response as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Oh, my goodness, you guys were quicker than I expected!

Doh! Might as well post my solution anyway!

```
foreach (var element in xml.Descendants("prompt"))
{
    Queue<string> pauses = new Queue<string>(Regex.Matches(element.Value, @"\[pause *= *\d+\]")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Value));
    Queue<string> text = new Queue<string>(element.Value.Split(pauses.ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.None));
    element.RemoveAll();
    while (text.Any())
    {
        element.Add(new XText(text.Dequeue()));
        if (pauses.Any())
            element.Add(new XElement("break", new XAttribute("time", Regex.Match(pauses.Dequeue(), @"\d+"))));
    }
}
```

For every prompt element, Regex match all your pauses and put them in a queue.

Then use these prompts to delimit the inner text and grab the 'other' text and put that in a queue.

Clear all data from the element using RemoveAll and then iterate over your delimited data and re-add it as the appropriate data type. When you are adding in the new attributes you can use Regex to get the number value out of the original match.